# Откат к предыдущему коммиту в git

Tags: git, git-commit

У меня есть проект, который дублирован на гите. Во время команды git pull гит показал мне, что у меня куча изменённых файлов, хотя в этой папке я изменений не делаю, а только сливаю изменения с гита. Скорее всего в проекте есть вредоносный код.

Теперь у меня вопрос: могу ли я использовать команду `git reset --hard HEAD~1`, чтобы откатить изменения, которые произошли в файлах проекта к состоянию, в котором они были на момент коммита `HEAD~1`? А потом накатить изменения, которые произошли между предпоследним и последним коммитом. Будет ли правильным такой способ?

Comment: А над проектом трудитесь только вы? Может, там важные изменения в той ветке, которую вы пуллите. Я бы для начала diff посмотрел

Comment: Да, проект исключительно мой. Последние изменения были около месяца назад. Больше ничего не менялось. Сейчас добавил буквально пару строк. Изменения только через гит, доступов к файлам проекта ни у кого нет.

Comment: @Mr. Brightside тем более, изменения в файлах точно не запланированные и точно вредоносные

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, у вас есть ряд изменений по сравнению с прошлым коммитом. Часть из них желательные и их нужно сохранить. Другая часть нежелательная, от них нужно избавиться. Так?

Comment: судя по вашему описанию, переключаться между коммитами — ни к чему. по крайней мере я не вижу смысла.

Comment: А коммит вообще был на вашей стороне или просто изменение файлов?

Comment: "Дублирован на гите" — это на каком-то облачном сервисе вроде GitHub?

Comment: @Nick Volynkin, не совсем. У меня есть локальная версия и есть версия на сервере. На локалке я добавил код и запушил. Всё ок. Когда я делаю git pull на сервере, он мне пишет, что есть очень-очень много изменений. Я понимаю, что эти изменения я не делал, т.к. на сервере я могу делать только git pull. Все изменения на локале, а там только обновлять. Теперь мне нужно избавится от всех изменений, т.е. откатиться до состояния прошлого коммита.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете откатывать не весь коммит, а только определенные пути — те, где у вас повреждены файлы. Это поможет сохранить те изменения, которые вы вносили самостоятельно.

```
git reset --hard HEAD^ -- /path1 /path2 somefile
```

Comment: Не, мне нужно откатить именно весь коммит. Чтобы все изменения всех файлов были отменены.